# Calling glBufferSubData several times per frame

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I´m doing a rendering where i call **glBufferSubData** several times per frame.

Here is how i do it in my code :

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,_vboID);

//Buffering the data
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,_vboDATA[type].size()*sizeof(vboData),nullptr,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,_vboDATA[type].size()*sizeof(vboData),_vboDATA[type].data());

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

I´m asking because i have a different types of elements and each has it´s own vector to represent vbo data(im using 1 VBO(for colors,UVs,positions - and 1 VAO) in my program and i´m doing the rendering like :

1.) Load vector of element 1 to buffer

2.) Render element 1

3.) Load vector of element 2 to buffer

4.) Render element 2

...

Is it a proper way to do it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way depends on your usage scenario. When the data is mostly static, then the best way is to upload the data once to the GPU. This can either be done by creating a VBO for each object, or by patching all objects together into a single VBO.

In case the data is fully dynamic (and changing in every frame), then you will have to upload the data anyway, so using just one buffer could be fine. But you should still try to get along with just uploading the data (`glBufferSubData`) and avoid allocating new memory (`glBufferData`) all over. You can, for example, choose an initial size of the buffer that is large enough to fit all your data. Another option would be to use [persistently mapped buffer](http://www.bfilipek.com/2015/01/persistent-mapped-buffers-in-opengl.html).

Comment: "then the best way is to create a VBO for each object" - that is highly debatable, not only be cause "the best" suggests you can apply one solution to every problem regarding static data regardless of he problem domain, but because you can, for instance, just as easily use one buffer, one index array and different vertex arrays which you enable and disable as needed and draw with `gl[Multi]DrawElementsBaseVertex`, for instance. Many ways to reach the goal here. Plus, you should point out the possibility of using persistently mapped buffers which you **don't** modify using `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: @thokra: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to include your suggestions into the answer.